# Uploading files to rackspace cloud files using php and windows server 2012 with IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, curl

Has anyone tried to use the PHP SDK for OpenStack/Rackspace API on a windows server with IIS?

The install instructions are:

You must install this library through Composer:

**Install Composer**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Require php-opencloud as a dependency**

```
php composer.phar require rackspace/php-opencloud:dev-master
```

Once you have installed the library, you will need to load Composer's autoloader (which registers all the required namespaces):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

And you're ready to go!

However,

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer
php & php composer.phar require rackspace/php-opencloud:dev-master
```

are linux commands.

Is there any way to ensure the dependencies on windows to ensure the SDK works correctly?